# How to get the number of rows of a spreadsheet without considering the hidden cells in xlrd?

Tags: python, xlrd

```
A B C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3   3
    4
    5
```

Consider this as the sheet where column C is hidden. Hence if find the nrows using:

```
nrow = sheet.nrows
```

it gives nrows as 5.
is there anyway to get the number of rows of the file by ignoring the hidden column.
I tried slicing the column, col(colx) but still i am getting the length of that object as 5

Comment: change the code to `nrow = sheet.nrows.replace(" ", "")`

Comment: sheet.nrows is int right? so how does replace work?

Comment: Sorry, i havent used nrow before, if that is the case you could try converting it to a string, then converting it back to an integer or you could use a mathematical algorithm to account for the unused rows

Comment: Hey, nrow returns the number of rows in that spreadsheet.
I was looking for an answer which doesnt need me iterating over the whole spreadsheet